# How to remove strange banding from PNG export with radial gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, gradient, cc-2014

I'm using Illustrator CC 2014 and have a radial gradient that looks smooth in edit, but gets really weird bands when I export or Save to Web (any format, all settings).

Here's how it looks in Illustrators artboard (just the top):

[image]

And here's how it looks after export!?

[image]

Notice the two light bands? How do I stop this?

Comment: Is your Illustrator document an RGB or CMYK document?

Comment: Banding is related to the number of colors you are writing.  But the fact that two of the bands are lighter than they should be appears to be due to a bug of some kind in your writer.

Comment: That's very bizarre (it doesn't look like posterization due to limited colors).  Are you sure you don't have some art there you're not aware of that might be rendering during the export?  Have you tried saving a copy, deleting all layers except this one?  Or recreating this shape & fill from scratch in a fresh document?

Comment: Along the lines of @RobCraig, maybe try pressing `Ctrl Y` to change viewing modes, and check that area for any extra lines that may represent additional art that you may not mean to have. `Ctrl Y` will also change your view back.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try adding a grain on top of the gradient- it will kind of simulate PS's gradient dither. Effects > Texture > Grain. It's a raster effect so not optimal, but it should help.

Answer (score 2):

[image: increase colors in save for web setting]
[image]

In illustrator save for web settings increase no of colors to get bands removed.